# Find the intersection between using two array

Tags: java

I have written Java code to find the intersection between two arrays

```
package CaseStudy;

public class Findintersection {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] series1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int[] series2 = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    for (int i = 0; i < series1.length; i++) {

      int x = series1[i];
      System.out.println(x + " ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < series2.length; j++) {
      int y = series2[j];
      System.out.println(y + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

I generated the individual values using for loop . But I am not able to use X and Y variable to compare the data.

I tried using IF conditions to compare the values.

```
 if (x==y);
         {
             System.out.println(x + " ");
         }
```

While comparing either X is not available or Y is not available.

Comment: `x` and `y` are defined in different blocks.

Comment: I am learning java on my own. How to define in same blocks?

Comment: "`if (x==y);`" remove the `;`.

Comment: you have to put it in the same scope, it will be better for you search what is scope  @saravanatn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, you just need to nest the 2nd `for` loop inside the 1st so that you compare each value in the 1st array with every value in the 2nd.

```
for (int i = 0; i < series1.length; i++) {
  int x = series1[i];

  for (int j = 0; j < series2.length; j++) {
    int y = series2[j];

    if(x == y)
      System.out.format("%d : (%d, %d)%n", x, i, j);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
3 : (2, 0)
4 : (3, 1)
5 : (4, 2)
```

Comment: [`System.out.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) could be used instead of `System.out.println(String.format(...))` in this case.

Comment: @WJS It prints the intersection between the 2nd instance of 4 in the first series and the instance in the 2nd series. The assumption is that these are lists, not sets.

Comment: The intersection of `[1,3,4,5]` and [`1,1,3,4,5]` should be `[1,3,4,5]`;

Comment: If the arrays are meant to represent sets rather than lists I would agree, but then [1,1,3,4,5] is not a valid set.